# Getting syntax error in __init__.py file of kivymd

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I downloaded the kivymd and kivy module and I'm using it in a python application. When I run my code this error appears:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:/Users/SA/Desktop/mhtiq-test/AI_PROCTOR-FYP-/main.py", line 10, in <module>
     from kivymd.app import MDApp
   File "C:\Users\SA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py", line 30
     fonts_path = os.path.join(path, f"fonts{os.sep}")
                                                    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can anyone tell how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f-strings were added in Python 3.6; you are using Python 3.5. You  need to upgrade your Python installation to use this code.

To make it compatible with Python 3.5, use the `format` method:

```
fonts_path = os.path.join(path, "fonts{}".format(os.sep))
```

Note that `os.path.join` appears to use `/` specifically, not `os.sep`, so doing this could produce somewhat of a hybrid path. Otherwise, you might also consider

```
fonts_path = os.path.join(path, "fonts", "")
```

to let `os.path.join` produce the trailing separator itself.

The `pathlib` module may also be an option, as it was introduced in Python 3.4.

Comment: Or you could use [future-fstrings](https://github.com/asottile/future-fstrings) which is a backport of fstrings to python<3.6

Comment: Eh, I'd be leery of using something that injects itself into the parsing process like this. Backporting library routines is one thing; backporting *syntax* is quite another.